# Download video using php webservice

Tags: php, web-services

I am pretty new in php so hopefully this all make sense.I am trying to make a web-service in php .I have an iphone app that is calling that web-service.I want to download video from url in database on calling that web-service.
Here php script for retrieving that url:

```
 $q="  Select url from videos where id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."'   ";
     $result=mysql_query($q);
           while( $rows =mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
            {
        $url=$rows['url '];
    //here i want code to download that file
        $myarray1=array("url "=>$url );
             }
```

I am using this script at following link to download file :
http://phpsnips.com/579/PHP-download-script-for-Large-File-Downloads#.U4wP_iiCLIU ...
but it not working.I have searched codes on google but i don't understand how to use for this scenario...

Comment: You might want to open that URL in the browser, or invoke that URL for it to download. You are retrieving a link, the link needs to be run for the download to commence

Comment: Please use `mysqli` or `PDO` and especially `prepared statements` or at least sanitise your input. Your script is very vulnerable to `sql injections`. Also, the `mysql_*` API is deprecated.

Comment: no it http call from iphone app ...i am not using browser..